# NLog: variable with cached layout yields different values if used multiple times

Tags: c#, nlog

I log to Azure Blob Storage and want to have one three logfiles (containing different things) per start and I use a cached timestamp for this. Ideally the timestamp should be the same in all three files, but they differ if I log to the specific targets at different times.

I set the variable like this

```
<variable name='blobprefix' value='${cached:cached=true:Inner=${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd\\THH.mm.ss}' />
```

And this is how I use it for every blob:

```
<target type="AzureBlobStorage"
    name="general-azureblob"
    connectionString="${blobConnection}"
    blobName="${blobprefix}.log"> 
</target>
```

How can I have the variable evaluate exactly once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [${processinfo:StartTime}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ProcessInfo-Layout-Renderer) like this:

```
<variable name='blobprefix' value='${processinfo:StartTime:format=yyyy-MM-dd\\THH.mm.ss:cached=true}' />
```

If you want to control the StartTime, then you can use [NLog GDC](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Gdc-Layout-Renderer) and do the following at application startup (Before creating the first NLog Logger-object):

```
NLog.GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("StartupTime", DateTime.UtcNow);
```

And have the following in NLog.config (`whenEmpty` is only there as fallback):

```
<variable name='blobprefix' value='${gdc:StartupTime:format=yyyy-MM-dd\\THH.mm.ss:cached=true:whenEmpty:${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd\\THH.mm.ss:cached=true}}' />
```

Comment: Thanks, I am not using NLog directly but via Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, but I will try this out.

Comment: @Panke Updated the answer with using ${processinfo:StartTime} as an alternative. Then no need to assign GDC.

Comment: Thanks, I am using your suggestion. It works great.